# phantom php echo?

Tags: php

im getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in /home/labvc/public_html/AT/site/getimages.php on line 26
```

from this code:

```
<?php

echo '<br />';
echo '<div id=gallery>';

function getDirTree($dir,$p=true) {
    $d = dir($dir);$x=array();
    while (false !== ($r = $d->read())) {
        if($r!="."&&$r!=".."&&(($p==false&&is_dir($dir.$r))||$p==true)) {
                $x[$r] = (is_dir($dir.$r)?array():(is_file($dir.$r)?true:false));
        }
    }

    foreach ($x as $key => $value) {
        if (is_dir($dir.$key."/")) {
                $x[$key] = getDirTree($dir.$key."/",$p);
        }
    }

    ksort($x);
    return $x;
}

$tree = getDirTree("./res/gallery/painting/");

foreach($tree as $element => $eval) {
    if (is_array($eval)) {
        foreach($eval as $file => $value) {
                if (strstr($file, "png")||strstr($file, "jpg")||strstr($file, "bmp")||strstr($file, "gif")) {
                        $item = $tree.'/'.$element.$file;
            $itemthumb = $tree.'/thumbs/'.$element.$file;
                        echo '<a href="'.$item.'"><img src="'.$itemthumb.'" alt="'.$file.'"/></a>';
                }
        }
    }
}

echo '</div>';


echo '<br />';

echo 'tree: '.$tree.'<br />';
echo 'element: '.$element.'<br />';
echo 'file: '.$file.'<br />';

$abc="res/gallery/painting";
$def="01.png";
echo'<a href="'.$abc.$def.'"><img src="'.$abc.'/thumbs/'.$def.'" alt="'.$def.'"/></a>';

echo '<br />';
```

line 26 is not an echo, theres not even an echo close to line 26

```
foreach($tree as $element => $eval) {
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know it sounds silly, but are you actually looking at / editing the file you are debugging?

Any number of times it turned out I was in directory A/foo.c, when the code was being run out of directory B/foo.c. I always feel stooooopid after doing this.

Stick a `print "foo!"` in there to see if you are actually in the file you think you are.

Comment: how very bizare, for some reason my other fileuploads to my server worked fine, but this one failed even though the transfer says it completed, so i deleted the one on the server, refreshed and reuploaded, now its working, thanks for the help :P

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, I've noticed that the probability of doing this particular stupid thing goes up exponentially after I've been working for more than 8 hours, sort of O((h-8)^2). I stopped pulling all-nighters 20 years ago when I started factoring in all the time it took the next day to fix all of the *clever* things I had done the night before.

Comment: Bahaha nice, i'm not at that stage yet, i make plenty good progress if i stay up, for example, two days ago i knew nothing about php, now i have basically swapped all my work over to it (php is awesome)

Comment: Ah, Grasshopper, but Python is more awesomer! (?)

Be careful about mixing your Business logic with your Presentation logic in your PHP pages. The language makes it *so* easy to do and it's a really bad habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a suspicious line:

```
$item = $tree.'/'.$element.$file;
```

`$tree` should be an array, so if you get the error at runtime (as opposed to compile time) then it would make sense it would complain about this.

Comment: nah i worked it out, my ftp client doesnt auto update the local list, so it tryed to upload a phantom version of my file, so no updates occured.